# Sharing Event Handler code between pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

How can you create event handling code in ASP.NET and share it between controls on several pages?

For example, two pages with

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCreated="NavigationItemCreated">
```

Rather than replicating it for each page I tried to put it into a class that both pages have access to

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCreated="MyHelper.NavigationItemCreated">
```

The class is as follows:

```
public class MyHelper
{
    public static void NavigationItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) { }
    public static string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

However, I get an error when I try to run (happens with or without `static`):

> **Compiler Error Message:** CS1061: 'ASP.page_default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'MyHelper' and no extension method 'MyHelper' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.page_default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can still access `MyProperty` with `<%# MyHelper.MyProperty %>`, so `MyHelper` can be used by the page, just not by event handlers.

**Update:**
Made the class and the event handling code static and that doesn't work either, neither does putting it into it's own namespace and using `MyNamespace.MyHelper.NavigationItemCreated`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user control, or make your own class which extends the standard Repeater class. In this custom control, you implement the common OnItemCreated functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

1. is your `MyHelper` class is in **APP_Code** ?
2. if it is than check for the namespace you included in you default page code-behind file which contains definition of `MyHelper` class

Comment: The class is in the App_Code file, no namespace (so should be in the global ASP namespace?). The fact that I can access properties OK suggests it is another issue

Comment: Page has no code behind: `<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" %>`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base page and put the common event handler code there.

Then in your child page that inherits from that base page, you can call the base page event handler method.

Doing this you'll have a central point to manage the common code! No need to change it everywhere.